# Sprite animation

Tags: xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone, 2d-games

I'm using this code to animate this sprite:

```
_ship = [[GameObject alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"SpaceFlier_sm_1.png" world:_world shapeName:@"SpaceFlier_sm_1" maxHp:10 healthBarType:HealthBarTypeGreen];

     CCSpriteFrameCache * cache =
    [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

    CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animation];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"SpaceFlier_s_2.png"]];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"SpaceFlier_s_3.png"]];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"SpaceFlier_s_4.png"]];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"SpaceFlier_s_5.png"]];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"SpaceFlier_s_6.png"]];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"SpaceFlier_s_7.png"]];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"SpaceFlier_s_8.png"]];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"SpaceFlier_s_2.png"]];


    animation.delayPerUnit = 0.05;

    [_ship runAction:
     [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
      [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]]];
```

It works very well.
Then, when i try to use this code for animate another sprite it doesn't work.

In this way:

```
if ((self = [super initWithSpriteFrameName:@"dragon.png" world:world shapeName:@"Boss_ship" maxHp:50 healthBarType:HealthBarTypeRed])) {
    _layer = layer;

    CCSpriteFrameCache * cache =
    [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

    CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animation];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"dragon2.png"]];
    [animation addSpriteFrame:
     [cache spriteFrameByName:@"dragon.png"]];



    animation.delayPerUnit = 0.05;

    [self runAction:
     [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
      [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]]];
```

I can see only dragon2.png, it doesn't change in dragon,png...

Answer (score 0):

Check that `dragon.png` is inside your sprite atlas or bundle resource. Also, double check the case in the filename matches exactly with your string.

Comment: Mmh, are you using separate png files or spriteAtlases? I'm assuming `self`is a `GameObject, isn't it? Inside which method is the second code snippet?

Comment: I'm using Sprites.pvr.ccz" and Sprites.plist. No self isn't a gameObject and _ship is a gameObject. I'm trying again, anda now the sprite change every time i restart the game...for explample: start1 dragon.png...restart. start2 dragon2.png...restart. start3 dragon.png ecc...really, i don't understand why. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What kind of object is `self`? Where are you allocating it? You could call the second animation on _ship, just to check is not a texture resources issue.